# Out of Memory error after VBA Macro has run successfully 3 times

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro which is working as it's supposed to; reads in large amount of data from .txt files (upwards of 2mil data points), does some filtering and calculations and then outputs to a spreadsheet.
However after running the macro 3 times VBA produces a Run-time error '7': Out of Memory.

My temporary solution has been to save, close and reopen excel (2010) which has allowed me to run the program a few more times - but this isn't a viable option when handing the program to the client.

This is the code, with the filtering taken out the middle. cellsArray is a variant array; strings and integers are input to it.

```
    For w = 0 To Listbox2count - 1

    Worksheets.Add(, ActiveSheet).Name = bookname

    ' open input text file
    myFile = ActiveWorkbook.path & "\" & SelectedTxtFileNames(w)
    Open myFile For Input As #1

    ReDim cellsArray(1048570, 12)

    Do While Not EOF(1)

        For i = 0 To 11

            ' some calculations here

            a = (i * ints) + counter + AMPMset * (ints * 11)
            cellsArray(a, 0) = bookname
            cellsArray(a, 1) = road
            cellsArray(a, 2) = approach
            cellsArray(a, 3) = detectorString
            cellsArray(a, 4) = dateString(0)
            cellsArray(a, 5) = IDate
            cellsArray(a, 8) = hours(i + 1)
            cellsArray(a, 9) = cars(0)
            If cellsArray(a, 9) = ":60" Then
                cellsArray(a, 9) = ":00"
                cellsArray(a, 8) = hours(i + 1) + 1
                If cellsArray(a, 8) = 24 Then
                    cellsArray(a, 8) = 0
                End If
            End If
            cellsArray(a, 10) = cars(i + 1)
            cellsArray(a, 11) = projectCode
        Next i

    Loop

    Range("A5:L" & a + 5) = cellsArray

    Close #1
    ReDim cellsArray(0)

Next w
```

The error is generated at this line:

```
Range("A5:L" & a + 5) = cellsArray
```

The dimensions of cellsArray have been decided by the max number of rows before the data is output to a new spreadsheet.

I've been watching the computer's memory usage using Task Manager while the macro runs; the memory usage peaks and falls as arrays are filled and emptied. The point when the Run-Time error occurs is usually when there is still available memory, so I'm really at a loss as to why this error is happening.

The Run-time error is still generated if I write over the same spreadsheet over and over again; so no more memory is being used by the spreadsheet itself.

It seems that a new chunk of memory is being used with each run of the macro; which I've only been able to clear by closing and reopening excel. Can anyone offer some solutions or advice?

Comment: Have you considered reading the data into a database? The translations that you are currently performing on a row by row basis could be done orders of magnitude quicker as a query out of a database.

Comment: Are you *really* using every single row (short 6) in a worksheet, columns A:L?

Comment: What are the values of `a` when it works and when it fails? Why not `Redim` once before the loop and once after, given that the size is always the same? If this leads to the solution, I would post as answer.

Comment: Please try `Erase cellsArray`instead of `ReDim cellsArray(0)`. `Erase` will free memory for dynamic arrays.

Comment: If this runs on Excel 2007/2010 you can save the file then save the workspace ([Application.SaveWorkspace Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff837602.aspx)) between cycles. This attempts to recover application environment. FWIW, I have found it to be flaky in Excel 2013; probably due to how the application window is handled.

Comment: I would try some of the suggestions above but also consider that if you are mapping *'upwards of 2mil data points'* per worksheet, you are allocating 12.5M array elements. That is 6× more memory than is required for each worksheet. There must be a more efficient method of memory allocation and subsequent data dump to each new worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't approve of manual data processing. Wouldn't it be easier to write a SQL for each of the worksheets and do your filtering/sorting in one query? Even if the file is not a typical CSV (comma delimited) you can always specify the delimiter, or split the rows using the `Mid` function as I did below. I imagine this will much more effective than writing it all in VBA:

```
 Sub CreateQuery()

        With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:=Array(Array( _
            "ODBC;DefaultDir=C:\[YOUR_PATH_TO_FILE];Driver={Microsoft Text-Treiber (*.txt; *.csv)};DriverId=27;FIL=text;MaxBufferSize"), Array(        "=2048;MaxScanRows=8;PageTimeout=5;SafeTransactions=0;Threads=3;UID=admin;UserCommitSync=Yes;")), Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
            .CommandType = 0
            .CommandText = Array( _
            '************Your SELECT QUERY BELOW**************** 
            "SELECT Mid(Test.`Col1;Col2`,1,InStr(Test.`Col1;Col2`,';')-1) AS 'T' FROM Test.txt Test" _ 
            )
            .RowNumbers = False
            .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
            .PreserveFormatting = True
            .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
            .BackgroundQuery = True
            .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
            .SavePassword = False
            .SaveData = True
            .AdjustColumnWidth = True
            .RefreshPeriod = 0
            .PreserveColumnInfo = True
            .ListObject.DisplayName = "Table_Query_from_Text_file"
            .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        End With
    End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

GD Lin,

Have you tried using

```
Erase cellsArray
```

?

This will eliminate the array completely and free up any reqources used by it ?
You recreate it in your loop in the beginning.

As per comments from Axel Richter.

Cheers